# How to find this convolution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus, convolution

How can I use *Mathematica* to find the convolution $f*f$ for

```
f[t_]:=Piecewise[
        {{t*(Pi - 4*t + t^2), Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 1]}, 
         {(-t)*(2 + t^2 - 4*Sqrt[-1 + t^2] - 2*ArcCsc[t] + 2*ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + t^2]]), 
           1 < t < Sqrt[2]
        }}, 0]
```

I would need a symbolic expression for the convolution. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the definition with `NIntegrate` ?

Answer (score 4):

Hard to do it analytically. Tried convolution theorem also. ForuierTransform had hard time with it as well as Integrate. So, here is a numerical solution.

The support needed is really only from $0$ to $2 \sqrt(2)$ since your function exist over $0$ to $\sqrt(2)$ but I integrated it over little larger range for the plot to look better.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence

```
  f[t_?NumericQ] := 
  Piecewise[{{t*(Pi - 4*t + t^2), 
     Inequality[0, Less, t, LessEqual, 
      1]}, {(-t)*(2 + t^2 - 4*Sqrt[-1 + t^2] - 2*ArcCsc[t] + 
        2*ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + t^2]]), 1 < t < Sqrt[2]}}, 0];
g[t_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[tao] f[t - tao], {tao, -Infinity, Infinity}]
data = Table[{t, g[t]}, {t, -0.5, 6, .01}];

Show[ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[f[t], {t, -.5, 6}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The red plot is the convolution and the blue curve is $f(t)$

Comment: Why not integrating over `-Infinity`, `Infinity` ? `NIntegrate` handles that well. Also, in your plot you can remove the little gap by adding `Exclusions->None`.

Comment: Just to make your `g` more generic.

Comment: Nasser, thank you for your answer, but can you get a symbolic expression for the convolution? Thanks.

Comment: @selinia are you sure an analytical solution exists?